# Where does this toolbar button exist in the menu?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone

I really try to avoid the mouse, but the toolbar drop-down that switches your Windows Phone Emulator target doesn't seem to have a corresponding menu item. Does anyone know where it is?

[image: Toolbar image]

Comment: I don't have the Phone Emulators installed to test for sure, but try pressing `Alt-B`, then `O` to open the Config Manager, and then arrow keys (or first letter) to choose wanted configuration.

Comment: That changes the configuration (Debug/Release or Arm/Any CPU), not which emulator to target.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly access the drop-down lists within the toolbars.

A workaround could be:

```
 ALT+F (to get into the menu)
 CTRL+TAB (to get to the toolbar)
 TAB TAB TAB TAB TAB (to get to the device dropdown)
 ARROW-DOWN (to open the dropdown)
 RETURN (to select a device)
```

that's a lot of keyboard actions